# Detect mouse position with conditions

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to obtain the following functionality:

When I run my script I need to record the `x,y` coordinates of the first time I press and release the mouse. I need this to work both on Linux and Windows.

I have been able to read the position of the mouse with

```
pyautogui.position()
```

How can I trigger this `position()` function by a mouse press/release? I would like to extend this to e.g. trigger with a mouse event only if the Alt key is pressed down.

Can someone point me in the right direction, I am a bit lost, and I cant find this in pyautogui's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check key press using keyboard :

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('alt'):
        print(pyautogui.position())
```

Comment: There is also a [mouse](https://github.com/boppreh/mouse) module that seems to be inspired by keyboard. It can be installed by pip. The appropriate command would be (I think -- I haven't tested this) `mouse.is_pressed(button='left')`

Comment: dude this is not the same thing he needs to check keypress and by this it will press left button of mouse.

Comment: Well, you're right in the sense that I didn't read the question that carefully. But OP is definitely asking how to detect a mouse press, and furthermore would like to detect ALT+mouse press. Tested solution is `if keyboard.is_pressed('alt') and mouse.is_pressed(button='left'): print(pyautogui.position())`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position only if the `Alt` key is pressed down and mouse `left` key is pressed by:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import mouse

if keyboard.is_pressed('alt') and mouse.is_pressed(button='left'):
    print(pyautogui.position())
```